# Apple Push Notifications - Invalid token using apnsclient

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm seeing a very strange behavior while using the `apnsclient` python package.

Here's what's involved:

- An iOS app distributed via TestFlight, so definitely in aps-**production** mode
- **Production** .pem certificate on my server
- For setting up the `apnsclient` connection, I'm using:

`session.get_connection('push_production', cert_file=...)`

I'm getting "Invalid token" responses (error code 8) from Apple.

***What's stranger***, however, is that I ***don't*** get the error if I switch my certificate over to the Development .pem ... so everything setup for production, but no errors if I supply the development certificate.

Unfortunately, despite the lack of error, no notification arrives.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the token was generated by your TestFlight version of the app and wasn't left in your database from a dev build?

Comment: @Paulw11 Positive - I cleared all the tokens for the account I'm testing.